# Cisco ASA VPN with static addresses

Tags: vpn, cisco

We have a group of machines that connect via the AnyConnect VPN software and get assigned a specific IP address. We then have software that sends data to that machine based on that IP. However, we have had a problem where that machine loses its connection, attempts to reconnect and gets a DHCP address rather than the static one we need.

The behavior we want is that if the machine attempts to login in even if the connection has not timed out that it would kill the older session and restart a new one and give it the correct address.

Is this possible? Any idea why we wouldn't get the right address?

Thanks!

Comment: Some more detail would help. How are you currently assigning IP addresses?

Comment: with a static "framed-ip-address" and it seems that subsequent sessions are issued address by a specified dhcp-server value

Answer (score 0):

As far as I remember, internal DHCP server provided by the Cisco ASA does not support IP address reservation with MAC address (https://supportforums.cisco.com/discussion/10344501/static-dhcp-ip-mac-address-reservation-asa). Therefore, I would suggest, that you could try using external DHCP server with Cisco ASA, and configure leases there:

http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/security/asa-5500-x-series-next-generation-firewalls/109493-asa-vpn-dhcp-asdm-config.html